# Retrofit: how can I specify the baseurl with a segment?

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I want to test with HttpUrl object to initialize the baseurl of Retrofit:

```
HttpUrl baseUrl = new HttpUrl.Builder()
                    .scheme("https")
                    .host("api-staging.xxxx.co")
                    .build();

            mRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                    .client(httpClient.build())
                    .build();
```

But I use a version information for each url, like that for example:
"https://api-staging.xxxx.co/v1/login"

So I want to specify the version in this configuration. So I tried like this:

- .host("api-staging.xxxx.co/v1/") > CRASH

And I don't want to add the version on each WS (mapping), so how can I do that properly guys?

Thank you very much!

Comment: does the version have to be added at runtime?

Comment: @Dracarys: no, not necessary

Answer (score 0):

u should not use

> .host("api-staging.xxxx.co/v1/")

the host just can be a domain name or ip address.

you can use "addPathSegment" method to add segment, or write like this:

`new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("api-staging.xxxx.co/v1/")`

Comment: just use .baseUrl(String base)  must be useful

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you want, but I usually state base URL in build.gradle of my module:

```
android {
...
    defaultConfig {
    ...
        buildConfigField("String", "BASE_URL", "\"https://api-staging.xxxx.co/v1/login\"")
    }
}
```

And then I use it like this:

```
BuildConfig.BASE_URL
```

Answer (score 0):

> But I use a version information for each url, like that for example:
>   "https://api-staging.xxxx.co/v1/login"

If you want to use dynamic url, you can build another instance of retrofit, that is is  good way. I used to use intercepter but it 's not good way when call a lot of api with different url continuously(it call wrong urls)
You can use this way:

```
public static Retrofit getClient(String baseURL) {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(baseURL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        } else {
            if (!retrofit.baseUrl().equals(baseURL)) {
                retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(baseURL)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .build();
            }
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

for others who need to add segment after baseUrl and before path:
you can use this interceptor:

```
/**
 * Interceptor that adds a prefix and/or suffix to the request URL path.
 *
 * @param prefix the prefix to add to the request URL path
 * @param suffix the suffix to add to the request URL path
 */
class UrlPathInterceptor(
    private val prefix: String? = null,
    private val suffix: String? = null
) : Interceptor {

    /**
     * Interceptor that adds a prefix and/or suffix to the request URL path.
     *
     * @param chain the chain of interceptors
     * @return the response from the next interceptor in the chain
     */
    override fun intercept(chain: Chain): Response {
        val request = chain.request()

        if (prefix.isNullOrBlank() && suffix.isNullOrBlank()) {
            return chain.proceed(request)
        }

        val httpUrl = request.url
        val newPath = buildNewPath(httpUrl.encodedPath)

        val newHttpUrl = httpUrl.newBuilder()
            .encodedPath(newPath)
            .build()

        val modifiedRequest = request.newBuilder()
            .url(newHttpUrl)
            .build()

        return chain.proceed(modifiedRequest)
    }

    /**
     * Builds the new path by cleaning the prefix, suffix, and path, and then joining them with a forward slash.
     *
     * @param path the path to clean and join
     * @return the new path
     */
    private fun buildNewPath(path: String): String {
        val cleanedPrefix = cleanPath(prefix)
        val cleanedSuffix = cleanPath(suffix)
        val cleanedPath = cleanPath(path)

        val parts = listOf(cleanedPrefix, cleanedPath, cleanedSuffix).filter { it.isNotBlank() }
        return parts.joinToString(separator = "/", prefix = "/", postfix = "/")
    }

    /**
     * Cleans the path by removing any leading or trailing forward slashes.
     *
     * @param path the path to clean
     * @return the cleaned path
     */
    private fun cleanPath(path: String?): String {
        return path?.removePrefix("/")?.removeSuffix("/")?: ""
    }
}
```

Then use it in your retrofit:

```
OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(UrlPathInterceptor(prefix =  "SomePrefix"))
            .build()
```